# What are dimensions of the B-17 propellers?

Tags: aerodynamics, propeller, b17-flying-fortress

I'm curious about the aerodynamics of the Boeing B-17 propeller, as the proportions looks perfect for a project I'm working up. Does anyone out there know where to find the specs/dimensions/models for the B-17 prop?

Answer (score 6):

According to the [maintenance manuals from here](https://ww2aircraft.net/forum/threads/b-17-manuals.5048/) about halfway down the page ([part 1 page 3](https://ww2aircraft.net/forum/attachments/b-17-maintanence-part-1-pdf.68569/)) the B-17 was equipped with:

> 7. PROPELLER.
>
>    - Type: Three-bladed, hydromatic, WEE50-473 or 505,
>        full feathering.
>        Mfgr.: Hamilton Standard.
>        Hub: 23E50-473.
>        Blade: 6477A-6.
>        Diam.: 11 ft. 7 in.

[Part two](https://ww2aircraft.net/forum/attachments/b-17-maintanence-part-2-pdf.68570/) of the manual has all the installation and setup instructions instructions if you are looking for those as well.

Hamilton Standard seems to have been acquired by (or turned into) [UTC Aerospace](https://utcaerospacesystems.com/product_gallery/propeller-systems/) which appears to still make propellers. You may want to reach out to them as they may have more info on hand. There are [quite a few B-17's lurking around](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_surviving_Boeing_B-17_Flying_Fortresses) and there may even be one near you that you can go take a look at and possibly even measure.